# How to handle KeyDown event in UWP ListBox?

Tags: events, listbox, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have loaded the ListBox within Popup, where I need to close the Popup when pressing the Enter key. But the KeyDown event is not fired for ListBox, which only works when the selection is in First or Last item. Any suggestions to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to global event - `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` and unsubscribe after popup will close